# Python chrome opens with “Data;” with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python selenium for web scraping, but after running the below codes, chrome is launched but did not get the website as I want, instead, it shows 'data;' in url bar.

Could anyone help with the problem? Many thanks!!

PS: My chrome is 88.and chromedriver is also 88. the path of chrome and chromedriver are different, one is in desktop and the other is C://

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    import time
    import random
    option = Options()
    option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    option.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Comment: I don't think you fully copied your code...

Comment: now the code is formatting

Comment: Worked perfectly for me as is, only changed the ```executable_path```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but how could I change the path to work, I mean does the problem cause by the chromedriver path?

Comment: @Yuki there is nothing wrong with the code. ```executable_path``` is just the path of the chromedriver. in order to make the code work in our system, we shall point the executable_path to our chromedriver.

Comment: Thanks Jiya, but I cannot run the code successfully in my computer,,just with blank page, no idea why

Comment: Okay I got the solution for your problem. Let me just neatly post the answer.

Comment: pls confirm the driver and chrome version again， It seems a version mismatch problem.

Comment: they are all up-to -date with 88.0.432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = options()
```

use this

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

and I would suggest you to put everything in the same project directory. which is a best practice.

---

Once you've put the chromedriver in the same directory.
do this:

```
from os import getcwd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(getcwd() + "\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

---

Also, try to close the old chrome windows.

Comment: Hey Jiya, thanks again but still no luck after changing the code, only launch to data; page and no jumping to my url

Comment: shows: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)

Comment: try this and please let me know. these are the best practices for selenium development.

Comment: Do you mean under the same path? I put them all in the desktop but it shows''chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH', sorry for lots of questions

Comment: I suggest you to put main.py and chromedriver.exe in one project folder (project directory )

Comment: I put anaconda, chrome and chromedriver in a folder already, do I also need to specify the path in the code?

Comment: ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(getcwd() + "\chromedriver.exe", options=options)```
this should work then, you can just copy paste it. 
dont forget ```from os import getcwd```

Comment: still got 'WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.', sad face..

Comment: sure, if you are available, thank you so much for your time! and I think I cannot get chrome app under the same folder with the other two as it is the default path for the chrome installation..may I have the contact we could connect ?

Answer (score 0):

It **will** go to `data://` and after that it will redirect to your website.
And also follow Jiya's answer as well.

Comment: Thanks Pal, but after a long time , it just launch data page but no jumping and then shows ' unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)'

Comment: @Yuki Does this error show in the console?

Comment: yes, if I exit the page manually. But when just waiting for the response it shows: WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages